# NPM install not working - one of the dependencies is missing

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

Whenever I try to execute `npm install` or `npm i`, I get this error:

```bash
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'json-parse-helpfulerror'
```

I cannot update NPM through `npm install npm -g` or `npm i npm -g`, becuase it produces the same error. My computer was very low on space, and I have a feeling it might have deleted one of NPM's dependenices. The actual `npm` command works though.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling npm will fix the issue.

```bash
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

If you're on Windows and you have a broken installation, the easiest thing to do is to reinstall node from the official installer.

You can also try clearing the cache

```bash
npm cache clean
```